# Applying a patch to the Shopware 6 Core

Tags: php, composer-php, patch, shopware6

My current version of Shopware has a small problem, for which I'd like to implement the following patch:
https://gitlab.com/mh2017/shopware6-patches/-/raw/master/core/variant-listing-updater.patch

To implement this patch I am using the `cweagans/composer-patches` plug-in. When running `composer update` the Shopware Core is attempted to be removed and re-installed:

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Removing package shopware/core so that it can be re-installed and re-patched.
  - Removing shopware/core (6.4.7.0)
```

However the removal of the Core fails, as the update command fails:

```
> [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare
ErrorException {#7
  #message: "Warning: include(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../shopware/core/Framework/Plugin/KernelPluginLoader/StaticKernelPluginLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
  #code: 0
  #file: "./vendor/symfony/error-handler/DebugClassLoader.php"
  #line: 349
  #severity: E_WARNING
  trace: {
    ./vendor/symfony/error-handler/DebugClassLoader.php:349 { …}
    ./bin/console:49 {
      › 
      › $pluginLoader = new StaticKernelPluginLoader($classLoader, null);
      › 
    }
  }
}
Script [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

This seems to be due to the fact that the core isn't there when attempting to run this command. When attempting to run this with the `--no-scripts` command, the command does run but also does not patch the Shopware version (as it is also a script).

**What would be the best way to apply patches to the Shopware core that also ensures that composer runs smoothly?**

Comment: We have encountered the same problems and removed the scripts in composer.json. We manually (read, it's in our pipelines) run the necessary commands.

Answer (score 0):

Write simple bash script like this and add it to composer script or run manually. I'm using this commands in my gitlab pipelines.

```bash
# apply commit
  curl -o /tmp/NEXT-21468.patch https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/285c5d4b6bf9f93f7ebfbbcb3354e95fb5adb6ee.patch
  git apply -p3 --directory='vendor/shopware/core' < /tmp/NEXT-21468.patch
# use sed to replace case sensitive path
  curl -o /tmp/NEXT-20216.patch  https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/bec6ac21a78ab84c7181dac2347e3e670f92033c.patch
  sed -i 's|/src/Core/|/src/core/|g' /tmp/NEXT-20216.patch
  sed -i 's|/src/Storefront/|/src/storefront/|g' /tmp/NEXT-20216.patch
  git apply -p2 --directory='vendor/shopware' < /tmp/NEXT-20216.patch
# apply pull request
 curl -o /tmp/NEXT-21994.patch https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/shopware/platform/pull/2536.patch
 git apply -p3 --directory='vendor/shopware/core' < /tmp/NEXT-21994.patch
```